# D3.js does not append HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js

I'm trying append to my existed HTML code the next:

```
<div id="bar-1" class="bar-main-container azure">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="bar-percentage" data-percentage="52"></div>
        <div class="bar-container">
            <div class="bar"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

for this I did:

```
var stats = d3.select("#language_stats")
    .append("div").attr("class", "bar-main-container azure")
    .append("div").attr("class", "wrap")
    .append("div").attr("class", "bar-percentage").attr("data-percentage", "52")
    .append("div").attr("class", "bar-container")
    .append("div").attr("class", "bar");
```

where

```
<div id="language_stats"></div>
```

but this code does not appending into my HTML. The block runs but does not append anything. What is the problem?

Also I'm a little bit struggled with this part,

```
<div class="bar-percentage" data-percentage="52"></div>
```

where closing `</div>` and `data-percentage` included.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `#language_stats`, another div? Besides that, your HTML is wrong: it misses a closing `</div>`.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado ah yes, sorry: `<div id="language_stats"></div>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is the structure you want to reproduce...

```
<div id="bar-1" class="bar-main-container azure">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="bar-percentage" data-percentage="52"></div>
        <div class="bar-container">
            <div class="bar"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

... you have to break the selection, otherwise you'll end up with a *matryoshka doll* of divs (a div inside a div inside a div...).

This is the code, pay attention to `innerDiv1` and `innerDiv2`:

```js
var stats = d3.select("#language_stats")
  .append("div")
  .attr("class", "bar-main-container azure")
  .append("div")
  .attr("class", "wrap");

var innerDiv1 = stats.append("div")
  .attr("class", "bar-percentage")
  .attr("data-percentage", "52");

var innerDiv2 = stats.append("div")
  .attr("class", "bar-container")
  .append("div")
  .attr("class", "bar");

console.log(d3.select(".bar-main-container").node())
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<div id="language_stats"></div>
```

Click "Run code snippet" and inspect the console in your browser (which will expand the element), not the Stack snippet result.